# How did this word problem related to linear congruences get $11x=17(mod24)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[image: congrue]

So if the first sentence is gone I'd intuitively get that it'd be $11x=17(mod24)$, but I think the first sentence regarding that it's an exact multiple of 1 hour that is less than 1 day is relevant to this.

Comment: The first sentence just says that $x$ is an integer and $0\leq x\lt 24$

Comment: Unless the orbital period is an integral number of hours, you can't conclude $11x\equiv17\pmod{24}$.  This congruence can only be solved up to a multiple of $24$, so if we don't know that the period is less than a day, we can't what it is exactly.